# Powershell adds quotes to splitted CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to split a csv file by the first digits of the longitude column. Here is a sample:

```
X,Y,TYPE,SPEED,DirType,Direction
-44.058251,-19.945982,1,30,1,339
-54.629503,-20.497509,1,30,1,263
-54.646202,-20.496151,1,30,1,86
```

I have no powershell knowledge but I found some script online and it did what I wanted:

```bsh
Import-Csv maparadar.csv 
| Group-Object -Property {($_.x)[0..2] -join ""} 
| Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; $_.group 
| Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation}
```

With this I get output files like -44.csv, -54.csv
But it adds unwanted quotes to every field in the output file like:

```
"X","Y","TYPE","SPEED","DirType","Direction"
"-46.521991","-23.690235","1","30","1","169"
"-46.670774","-23.756021","1","30","1","281"
"-46.549897","-23.120720","1","30","1","99"
```

Is there any way I can export the csv without adding those quotes?

Comment: that is the "official" way that CSV files should be. [*grin*] unfortunately, the current versions of PoSh don't allow disabling that. [*sigh ...*] if you want to remove them, you will need to load the file with `Get-Content` and then use one of the string replace operators/methods to remove them.

Comment: I haven't tried this but what output do you get without the -csv switch? I guess you should get an unprocessed txt file (but with csv extension, as it is specified in your path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should provide the desired output:

```
Import-Csv maparadar.csv | 
    Group-Object -Property {($_.x)[0..2] -join ""} | 
      Foreach-Object { $path=$_.name+".csv" ; ($_.group |
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -Replace '"' |
          Set-Content -Path $path }
```

**Explanation:**

We replaced your `Export-Csv` with `ConvertTo-Csv`, which provides the CSV output to the console/pipeline rather than outputting to the file. Those CSV formatted outputs are sent through the `-Replace` operator to replace the literal `"` characters. Finally the formatted output is sent to the desired file using `Set-Content -Path $path`.

Comment: What happens if the data contains QUOTATION MARK `"` characters?

Comment: @lit, `($csv | convertto-csv -notype) -replace '(?<=,|^)"|"(?=,|$)' -replace '("){2,}','$1'` will do that. I didn't see extra quotes in the example, though.

Comment: Quotes are also needed if a value contains the used delimiter character. Stripping away quotes could result in bad csv files..